# How to debug a hung process in AIX platform?

Tags: ksh, aix

I found that there are several processes are hung(DeFun) in AIX machine.
Those processes are created by a k-shell script, however, I found the script can be executed successfully without hung when I executed manually.

So, is there way to debug the hung process?

Answer (score 0):

A defunct process is a process that has terminated and just needs to tell his parent that he is finished (returning an exit code). The proces itself doesn't need to be debugged, you must look at the parent process.
When you start the process from the commandline, the ksh will wait for the result of the script. Your parent script/executable should call a wait to learn about his children.
For more information, just look for defunct or zombie.